# Redirect ETW event logs to remote machine in local LAN

Tags: c#, etw

I have implemented a C# code for event logging using ETW mechanism. Its works fine and I am able to log all the events in the event viewer. But my requirement is to redirect all the logs generated by my application to another remote computer within local network.
Can anybody help me to know the C# code sample using ETW logging technology to register all the logs in remote machine.

Thanks
Lav

Comment: how do you capture the ETW events?

Answer (score 1):

You should configure a 'collector' machine to subscribe to events at 'worker' machine. Check out [Configure Computers to Forward and Collect Events](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748890.aspx) article.